# Why does the JavaScript in my *.ascx file not display in CDT?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chrome

I want to step through some JavaScript in my *.ascx page, which contains, in part:

```
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  . . .

  $("#saveData").click(function () {
      alert('you clicked the saveData button');
      var loc = window.location.href;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: loc + "/SaveEnteredValues",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
      });
  });
</script>
```

...but CDT does not seem to be making that file available for perusal. This is all I see in CDT=>Sources:

[image]

Why is it hiding the JavaScript in *.ascx, and how can I view /step through it?

Comment: JS in the `ascx` file will show up in your destination `aspx` page. Try looking for it in `FinAff_demo_Page_Clay.aspx`. Alternatively you can put your script file somewhere else and link to it (highly recommended)

Comment: Make that an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript between `<script>` tags inside an `.ascx` file will show up in the `.aspx` page that loads the control.

In your example you'll be able to step through the code by selecting `FinAff_demo_Page_Clay.aspx`.

I would generally recommend linking to an external JS file though, so that you can do typical stuff like transpile, minify etc.